# ¿Cómo mostrar una imagen guardada en phpmyadmin con formato BLOB pero con sesiones?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, session

Quiero mostrar con HTML y PHP una imagen guardada en una base de datos MySQL, en una página web.

Inicialmente capturé los datos desde la base de datos MySQL de phpmyadmin de una imagen con un `get`:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['pro'])): ?>
```

Donde en la misma página con este código:

```
<img class="img-center img-responsive" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo "".$_SESSION[base64_encode($result[0]['prodImg']); ?>" alt="">`
```

La imagen se muestra correctamente, el problema viene cuando quiero que eso se guarde en una sesión para seguir pasando esa imagen a otras páginas donde va a seguir un proceso, ya sin tener que jalarla directamente de la base de datos.

Puse esto en la primera página:

```
<?php
$imagen = $result[0]['prodImg'];
$_SESSION['variable9']=$imagen;
```

Luego en la siguiente página donde todos los demás datos complementarios de la imagen me cargan correctamente con la sesión, lo que no me carga ya es la imagen.

Éste es el código con el que quiero mostrar la imagen en la siguiente página:

```
<img style="max-height: 200px" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo "".$_SESSION[base64_encode('variable9')]; ?>" alt="">`
```

Lo he puesto de muchas formas y ninguno me funciona.

Nota: Con este mismo proceso otros datos sí me cargan. Por ejemplo:

Primera página:

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
session_start();
}  
?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])): ?>
<?php if(isset($_GET['pro'])): ?>
<?php 
$class= new cProducto();
$idUsuario=$_SESSION['id'];
$result2 = $class->getUsuarioForId($idUsuario);
$result = $class->getProductForId($_GET['pro']);

$name = strtoupper($result[0]['prodNombre']);
$idProducto= $result[0]['idProducto'];
$ancho = $result[0]['prodAncho'];
$alto = $result[0]['prodAlto'];
$categoria = $result[0]['idCategoria'];
$imagen = $result[0]['prodImg'];

$nomPer = $result2[0]['nombrersocial'];
$numero = $result2[0]['numero'];
$dni = $result2[0]['dniruc'];
$_SESSION['variable1']=$idProducto;
$_SESSION['variable2']=$name;
$_SESSION['variable3']=$ancho;
$_SESSION['variable4']=$alto;
$_SESSION['variable5']=$categoria;
$_SESSION['variable6']=$nomPer;
$_SESSION['variable7']=$numero;
$_SESSION['variable8']=$dni;
$_SESSION['variable9']=$imagen;
?>
```

Segunda Página:

```
<?php session_start();
?>
<pre style="text-align: justify; margin: 10px;"><?php echo "Código              :       ".$_SESSION['variable1']; ?></pre>
<pre style="text-align: justify; margin: 10px;"><?php echo "Nombre del producto :       ".$_SESSION['variable2']; ?></pre>
<pre style="text-align: justify; margin: 10px;"><?php echo "Ancho               :       ".$_SESSION['variable3']; ?></pre>
<pre style="text-align: justify; margin: 10px;"><?php echo "Alto                :       ".$_SESSION['variable4']; ?></pre>
```

Y así sucesivamente todos los datos se muestran correctamente menos la imagen.

Comment: Por favor, redacta bien tu pregunta utilizando los [marcadores de formato](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Al principio usas `$_SESSION[base64_encode($result[0]['prodImg']);`pero esto no deberia funcionar nunca si no la has guardado antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas montando un lio tremendo con la codificación y las sesiones.

Recupera la imagen así siempre

```
$imagen = $result[0]['prodImg'];
$_SESSION['variable9']=$imagen;
```

Y en todos los sitios donde la tengas que usar haz

```
base64_encode($_SESSION['variable9'])
```

En tu caso

```
<img style="max-height: 200px" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo "".base64_encode($_SESSION['variable9']); ?>" alt="">
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me ha funcionado perfectamente ahora si :)

Answer (score 0):

Estás codificando en base64 con `base64_encode()` en el orden incorrecto. Debes usar:

```
<img style="max-height: 200px"
  src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?= base64_encode($_SESSION['variable9']) ?>"
  alt="" />
```

Te está fallando porque estás tratando de obtener el índice de la variable de sesión `$_SESSION` que coincide con la codificación en base64 del texto `variable9`, en vez de obtener el índice `variable9` y su contenido codificarlo en base64.

Por cierto, no es nada recomendable guardar grandes cantidades de datos en las variables de sesión ya que éstas serán cargadas y guardadas en cada carga de un PHP (tras llamar a `session_start()`) aunque no haga uso de esas variables. Tu servidor se irá resintiendo poco a poco. Procura dejar en `$_SESSION` lo mínimo indispensable para identificar al usuario de la sesión.