# Agregar formato a una imagen a partir de un blob PHP

Tags: php, imagen, blob

Estoy creando una `API` con **PHP** y **codeigniter** la cual se utiliza para consultar datos de artículos, almacenados en una base de datos en `Frebird`, y los pasa como `json`. El problema que me surgió es que las imágenes de los artículos están almacenadas como `blob` pero sin su formato (les falta el .jpg) y no estoy encontrando la forma de agregarselo.
Espero haber sido claro y que me puedan ayudar, desde a gracias.
Les dejo la parte del código que tengo actualmente.

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);  
$row = $query->row();  
ob_start();  
imagejpeg($row -> IMAGEN);  
$imageData = ob_get_contents();  
ob_clean();  
$info = pathinfo($imageData);  
$row -> IMAGEN = base64_encode($imageData);  
echo json_encode(array($row));
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Ese código que estás publicando no es correcto. Los parámetros de entrada a `imagejpeg()` no tienen sentido. Si los datos binarios de la imagen JPEG están en la base de datos, puedes enviarlos directamente al navegador sin pasar por dicha función. ¿Podrías poner en contexto ese código PHP? Es decir, usas algo como `<img src="archivo.php" />` para mostrar la imagen? Lo digo porque también es raro el envío que haces haciendo uso de `json_encode()`... parec que lo recibe una llamada XHR desde javascript.

Comment: Hola y muchas gracias. Envió los datos mediante <code> json_enconde() <code> porque los recibe una ** APP ** creada con ** Xamarin ** la cual decodifica el ' json '  para poder manipular los datos. Y estoy teniendo problemas porque a las  imágenes le quitaron el .JPG al almacenarlas en en la base de datos como ' blob '.

Comment: A ver, depende de cómo trate el resultado ese Xamarin, puedes enviar los datos sin usar `base64_encode` o bien debes formar correctamente un campo `src` en línea. ¿Podrías dar algo más de información de cómo recibe la aplicación Xamarin esa imagen para asignarla a una imagen? Quizá simplemente necesitas formar la cadena como especifica [el estándar de codificación de datos en URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Datos_URIs).

Comment: ¿Necesitas devolver los datos en una propiedad específica? ¿Se hace una decodificación JSON o no? Echa un vistazo a cómo se crea una URI con datos de imagen, por ejemplo, en esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178876/cómo-mostrar-una-imagen-guardada-en-phpmyadmin-con-formato-blob-pero-con-sesion/178901#178901

Comment: ¿Qué tal te fue? Vi una notificación con una vista preliminar de tu mensaje, pero parece que lo borraste.

Comment: Gracias por preocuparte por ayudarme y me surgieron otras cuestiones por eso no respondí. Ya lo eh solucionado con con solo una función adicional al código que publique.  <code>    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
   $row = $query->row();
    $x = imagecreatefromstring($row -> IMAGEN);
   ob_start();
   imagejpeg($x);
   $x = ob_get_contents();
   ob_clean();
   $row -> IMAGEN = base64_encode($x);
   echo json_encode(array($row));</code> Te agradezco.

Comment: Pero el contenido del blob ¿es una imagen JPEG? Si es así estás recomprimiendo. Es decir, estás perdiendo calidad de imagen por descomprimir el JPEG y volver a comprimir para generar un nuevo JPEG.

Comment: Te he redactado una respuesta con la solución óptima. Espero que te sea de ayuda y, sobre todo, te ayude a no perder calidad de imagen en el proceso.

Comment: puedes hacer esto: `<img style="max-height: 200px" src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row["imagen"]);?>"/>`

Comment: ¿Pudiste probar si mi respuesta soluciona tu problema sin recomprimir tu imagen?

Answer (score 0):

En tu código estás generando incorrectamente la imagen que debes enviar a la aplicación porque estás pasando como parámetro el contenido binario de la imagen a [`imagejpeg()`](http://php.net/es/imagejpeg), que requiere pasar como parámetro el recurso creado con, por ejemplo, [`imagecreatetruecolor()`](http://php.net/es/imagecreatetruecolor) que será convertido a JPEG.

En su lugar he almacenado en la misma propiedad, `$row->IMAGEN`, los datos binarios codificados en BASE64 que se almacenaban en ella:

```
<?php
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$row = $query->row();
$info = pathinfo($imageData);
$row->IMAGEN = base64_encode($row->IMAGEN);
echo json_encode(array($row));
```

NOTA: La solución que has descrito en los comentarios es subóptima porque estás descomprimiendo una imagen JPEG con `$x = imagecreatefromstring($row -> IMAGEN);` y luego volviendo a comprimir en JPEG con `imagejpeg($x);`, perdiendo calidad de imagen por la recompresión. Los formatos de imagen con pérdida como JPEG pierden progresivamente calidad conforme se descomprimen y se recomprimen de nuevo, incluso aunque uses el parámetro de calidad al 100% nunca se conseguirá con dicho formato mantener la calidad original.